# React.js - update component immediately on onChange event

Tags: reactjs

**TLDR**: How do I get a component to update immediately on a textarea onChange event in another component?

I'm building a small JSON formatter app in order to learn React. I have an `InputArea` component to enter the JSON, and an `OutputArea` component to display the formatted JSON, both within my `App` component. I have a basic working example except that the formatted output is appearing one step behind it being entered into the textarea. I realise this is to do with `setState` and the fact that the state transition is pending rather than immediate. I believe I can use an updater callback with `setState`, or, as is recommended, use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method, but I can't get my head around what I need to do in `componentDidUpdate` to get `setState` to update?

The code is not great, I'm just trying to get it working for now.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      inputValue: "Paste your JSON here.",
      outputValue: "",
      hasError: false,
      errorValue: ""
    }

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }


  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value })
    let parsed = ""
    try {
      parsed = JSON.parse(this.state.inputValue)
    } catch (e) {
      this.setState({
        hasError: true,
        errorValue: e
      })
      return
    }
    const formatted = JSON.stringify(parsed, null, 2)
    this.setState({
      outputValue: formatted,
      hasError: false,
      errorValue: ""
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Formatter-tat-tat</h1>
        </header>
        <InputArea
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <OutputArea
          hasError={this.state.hasError}
          value={this.state.outputValue}
          error={this.state.errorValue}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default class InputArea extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="input-area">
        <form>
          <label>
            JSON:
            <textarea
              value={this.props.value}
              onChange={this.props.handleChange}
            />
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default class OutputArea extends Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.hasError) {
      return (
        <div className="output-area">
          <p>Error: {this.props.error.toString()}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (
      <div className="output-area">
        <pre>{this.props.value}</pre>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are one step before because exactly this code part:

```
1. this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value })
2. let parsed = ""
3. try {
4.  parsed = JSON.parse(this.state.inputValue)
5. }
...
```

Lets go through above lines:

**Line 1:** You are using setState to push your component into new state, but as you said in the question it is not immediately action. So the change is not here yet.

**Line 4:** You are using the old state value, because as I've described in line 1 the change of the state is not reflected in this.state yet.

**The fix:** In the line 4 use `event.target.value` instead of out-dated `this.state.inputValue`

Comment: Ahhhh, right, I was looking at the wrong sequence of events, I was looking one step ahead at what was happening after `JSON.parse()`. Thankyou! This is a great, clear answer.